# Does omitting "in" from "take a rest in" make a material difference?

Tags: prepositions

Do these two sentences make sense?

> 1. We looked for a cafe to take a rest in.
> 2. We looked for a cafe to take a rest.

If so, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: You may find that the English Language Learners site is more appropriate to this type of question. I would suggest you place it there.

Comment: Is the cafe the one that will be taking a rest?

Comment: @Drew: are you intentionally trying to mislead the innocent OP? Both sentences are fine, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @TonyK: No, actually I think that if the second is to clearly have the meaning you suppose, it had better have a comma after *cafe*. But sure, English with both correct and incorrect grammar can be ambiguous.

Comment: @Drew: the only way to misunderstand the second sentence is to deliberately misunderstand it.

Comment: @TonyK: I'm *looking for you to* explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Only about five percent of hits in the *Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(take%20a%20rest%20in)%2F(take%20a%20rest%20%2B%20take%20a%20rest%20in)&year_start=1876&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28take%20a%20rest%20in%29%20/%20%28take%20a%20rest%20%2B%20take%20a%20rest%20in%29%3B%2Cc0)* of ***"take a rest"*** continue with **"in"**.

Answer (score 1):

There are times when prepositions are vital to aid understanding.  This is not among them.

*"We looked for a cafe to take a rest."* is a perfectly acceptable way to express the idea.  It was suggested in the comments that that could be misunderstood - that the Cafe could be the one doing the resting.  Strict grammar allows that misunderstanding, but context rules it out.  If I actually wanted to indicate that the cafe would be doing the resting, I would have to do some serious gymnastics to override the reader's common sense: *"We looked for a cafe that was able and willing to take a rest, just as an animal or person would."*

An example where the preposition *could be* necessary:  *We chose a room to paint.*  This might mean that you are painting the room, but could also mean you are painting portraits within the room.  Again, extended context would probably make it clear.